# WorldWind line of sight

Tags: java, gis, worldwind

I've found this example of how to render line of sight in WorldWind:  http://patmurris.blogspot.com/2008/04/ray-casting-and-line-of-sight-for-wwj.html  (its a bit old, but it still seems to work).  This is the [class](http://www.alpix.com/3d/worldwin/WWJ/LineOfSight.java.txt) used in the example  (slightly modified code below to work with WorldWind 2.0).  It looks like the code also uses RayCastingSupport ([Javadoc](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.4/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/util/RayCastingSupport.html) and [Code](https://gitorious.org/worldwind/worldwind/source/dd7e29508d3c77e09873f7c6539ef465fe99c69b:src/gov/nasa/worldwind/examples/util/RayCastingSupport.java)) to do its magic.

What I'm trying to figure out is if this code/example is using the curvature of the earth/and or the distance to the horizon as part of its logic. Just looking at the code, I'm not sure I understand completely what it is doing.

For instance, if I was trying to figure out what terrain a person 200 meters above the earth could "see", would it take the distance to the horizon into account?

What would it take to modify the code to account for distance to the horizon/curvature of the earth (if its not already)?

```
package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.util.RayCastingSupport;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.view.orbit.OrbitView;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Angle;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Sector;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Vec4;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.globes.Globe;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.CrosshairLayer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.RenderableLayer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class LineOfSight extends ApplicationTemplate
{
    public static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame
    {
        private double samplingLength = 30; // Ray casting sample length
        private int centerOffset = 100; // meters above ground for center
        private int pointOffset = 10;   // meters above ground for sampled points
        private Vec4 light = new Vec4(1, 1, -1).normalize3();   // Light direction (from South-East)
        private double ambiant = .4;                            // Minimum lighting (0 - 1)

        private RenderableLayer renderableLayer;
        private SurfaceImage surfaceImage;
        private ScreenAnnotation screenAnnotation;
        private JComboBox radiusCombo;
        private JComboBox samplesCombo;
        private JCheckBox shadingCheck;
        private JButton computeButton;

        public AppFrame()
        {
            super(true, true, false);

            // Add USGS Topo Maps
//            insertBeforePlacenames(getWwd(), new USGSTopographicMaps());

            // Add our renderable layer for result display
            this.renderableLayer = new RenderableLayer();
            this.renderableLayer.setName("Line of sight");
            this.renderableLayer.setPickEnabled(false);
            insertBeforePlacenames(getWwd(), this.renderableLayer);

            // Add crosshair layer
            insertBeforePlacenames(getWwd(), new CrosshairLayer());

            // Update layer panel
            this.getLayerPanel().update(getWwd());

            // Add control panel
            this.getLayerPanel().add(makeControlPanel(),  BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        private JPanel makeControlPanel()
        {
            JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
            controlPanel.setBorder(
                new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(9, 9, 9, 9),
                new TitledBorder("Line Of Sight")));

            // Radius combo
            JPanel radiusPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
            radiusPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
            radiusPanel.add(new JLabel("Max radius:"));
            radiusCombo = new JComboBox(new String[] {"5km", "10km",
                    "20km", "30km", "50km", "100km", "200km"});
            radiusCombo.setSelectedItem("10km");
            radiusPanel.add(radiusCombo);

            // Samples combo
            JPanel samplesPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
            samplesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
            samplesPanel.add(new JLabel("Samples:"));
            samplesCombo = new JComboBox(new String[] {"128", "256", "512"});
            samplesCombo.setSelectedItem("128");
            samplesPanel.add(samplesCombo);

            // Shading checkbox
            JPanel shadingPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 0));
            shadingPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
            shadingPanel.add(new JLabel("Light:"));
            shadingCheck = new JCheckBox("Add shading");
            shadingCheck.setSelected(false);
            shadingPanel.add(shadingCheck);

            // Compute button
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
            buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
            computeButton = new JButton("Compute");
            computeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                {
                    update();
                }
            });
            buttonPanel.add(computeButton);

            // Help text
            JPanel helpPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
            buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));
            helpPanel.add(new JLabel("Place view center on an elevated"));
            helpPanel.add(new JLabel("location and click \"Compute\""));

            // Panel assembly
            controlPanel.add(radiusPanel);
            controlPanel.add(samplesPanel);
            controlPanel.add(shadingPanel);
            controlPanel.add(buttonPanel);
            controlPanel.add(helpPanel);

            return controlPanel;
        }

        // Update line of sight computation
        private void update()
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    computeLineOfSight();
                }
            }, "LOS thread").start();
        }

        private void computeLineOfSight()
        {
            computeButton.setEnabled(false);
            computeButton.setText("Computing...");

            try
            {
                Globe globe = getWwd().getModel().getGlobe();
                OrbitView view = (OrbitView)getWwd().getView();
                Position centerPosition = view.getCenterPosition();

                // Compute sector
                String radiusString = ((String)radiusCombo.getSelectedItem());
                double radius = 1000 * Double.parseDouble(radiusString.substring(0, radiusString.length() - 2));
                double deltaLatRadians = radius / globe.getEquatorialRadius();
                double deltaLonRadians = deltaLatRadians / Math.cos(centerPosition.getLatitude().radians);
                Sector sector = new Sector(centerPosition.getLatitude().subtractRadians(deltaLatRadians),
                        centerPosition.getLatitude().addRadians(deltaLatRadians),
                        centerPosition.getLongitude().subtractRadians(deltaLonRadians),
                        centerPosition.getLongitude().addRadians(deltaLonRadians));

                // Compute center point
                double centerElevation = globe.getElevation(centerPosition.getLatitude(),
                        centerPosition.getLongitude());
                Vec4 center = globe.computePointFromPosition(
                        new Position(centerPosition, centerElevation + centerOffset));

                // Compute image
                float hueScaleFactor = .7f;
                int samples = Integer.parseInt((String)samplesCombo.getSelectedItem());
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(samples, samples, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                double latStepRadians = sector.getDeltaLatRadians() / image.getHeight();
                double lonStepRadians = sector.getDeltaLonRadians() / image.getWidth();
                for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
                {
                    Angle lon = sector.getMinLongitude().addRadians(lonStepRadians * x + lonStepRadians / 2);
                    for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++)
                    {
                        Angle lat = sector.getMaxLatitude().subtractRadians(latStepRadians * y + latStepRadians / 2);
                        double el = globe.getElevation(lat, lon);
                        // Test line of sight from point to center
                        Vec4 point = globe.computePointFromPosition(lat, lon, el + pointOffset);
                        double distance = point.distanceTo3(center);
                        if (distance <= radius)
                        {
                            if (RayCastingSupport.intersectSegmentWithTerrain(
                                    globe, point, center, samplingLength, samplingLength) == null)
                            {
                                // Center visible from point: set pixel color and shade
                                float hue = (float)Math.min(distance / radius, 1) * hueScaleFactor;
                                float shade = shadingCheck.isSelected() ?
                                        (float)computeShading(globe, lat, lon, light, ambiant) : 0f;
                                image.setRGB(x, y, Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, 1f, 1f - shade));
                            }
                            else if (shadingCheck.isSelected())
                            {
                                // Center not visible: apply shading nonetheless if selected
                                float shade = (float)computeShading(globe, lat, lon, light, ambiant);
                                image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, shade).getRGB());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Blur image
                PatternFactory.blur(PatternFactory.blur(PatternFactory.blur(PatternFactory.blur(image))));

                // Update surface image
                if (this.surfaceImage != null)
                    this.renderableLayer.removeRenderable(this.surfaceImage);
                this.surfaceImage = new SurfaceImage(image, sector);
                this.surfaceImage.setOpacity(.5);
                this.renderableLayer.addRenderable(this.surfaceImage);

                // Compute distance scale image
                BufferedImage scaleImage = new BufferedImage(64, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                Graphics g2 = scaleImage.getGraphics();
                int divisions = 10;
                int labelStep = scaleImage.getHeight() / divisions;
                for (int y = 0; y < scaleImage.getHeight(); y++)
                {
                    int x1 = scaleImage.getWidth() / 5;
                    if (y % labelStep == 0 && y != 0)
                    {
                        double d = radius / divisions * y / labelStep / 1000;
                        String label = Double.toString(d) + "km";
                        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g2.drawString(label, x1 + 6, y + 6);
                        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g2.drawLine(x1, y, x1 + 4 , y);
                        g2.drawString(label, x1 + 5, y + 5);
                    }
                    float hue = (float)y / (scaleImage.getHeight() - 1) * hueScaleFactor;
                    g2.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, 1f));
                    g2.drawLine(0, y, x1, y);
                }

                // Update distance scale screen annotation
                if (this.screenAnnotation != null)
                    this.renderableLayer.removeRenderable(this.screenAnnotation);
                this.screenAnnotation = new ScreenAnnotation("", new Point(20, 20));
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setImageSource(scaleImage);
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setSize(
                        new Dimension(scaleImage.getWidth(), scaleImage.getHeight()));
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setAdjustWidthToText(Annotation.SIZE_FIXED);
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setDrawOffset(new Point(scaleImage.getWidth() / 2, 0));
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setBorderWidth(0);
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setCornerRadius(0);
                this.screenAnnotation.getAttributes().setBackgroundColor(new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
                this.renderableLayer.addRenderable(this.screenAnnotation);

                // Redraw
                this.getWwd().redraw();
            }
            finally
            {
                computeButton.setEnabled(true);
                computeButton.setText("Compute");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Compute shadow intensity at a globe position.
         * @param globe the <code>Globe</code>.
         * @param lat the location latitude.
         * @param lon the location longitude.
         * @param light the light direction vector. Expected to be normalized.
         * @param ambiant the minimum ambiant light level (0..1).
         * @return  the shadow intensity for the location. No shadow = 0, totaly obscured = 1.
         */
        private static double computeShading(Globe globe, Angle lat, Angle lon, Vec4 light, double ambiant)
        {
            double thirtyMetersRadians = 30 / globe.getEquatorialRadius();
            Vec4 p0 = globe.computePointFromPosition(lat, lon, 0);
            Vec4 px = globe.computePointFromPosition(lat, Angle.fromRadians(lon.radians - thirtyMetersRadians), 0);
            Vec4 py = globe.computePointFromPosition(Angle.fromRadians(lat.radians + thirtyMetersRadians), lon, 0);

            double el0 = globe.getElevation(lat, lon);
            double elx = globe.getElevation(lat, Angle.fromRadians(lon.radians - thirtyMetersRadians));
            double ely = globe.getElevation(Angle.fromRadians(lat.radians + thirtyMetersRadians), lon);

            Vec4 vx = new Vec4(p0.distanceTo3(px), 0, elx - el0).normalize3();
            Vec4 vy = new Vec4(0, p0.distanceTo3(py), ely - el0).normalize3();
            Vec4 normal = vx.cross3(vy).normalize3();

            return 1d - Math.max(-light.dot3(normal), ambiant);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationTemplate.start("World Wind Line Of Sight Calculation", AppFrame.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not really going for a "Why isn't this code working?" question, its more of a "Can you tell me how this code works?" type of question.   I'll think about how I can make the code included more "minimal", but I also wanted to include everything to reproduce exactly what the blog post is talking about.

Comment: I may (or may not) provide a detailed, canonical answer to address the concerns in a followup, but short-and-sweet the "key" to how the code works is in the call to RayCastingSupport.intersectSegmentWithTerrain( )

Comment: The method this routine is using is a ray-casting algorithm to dot-product the surface normal of the globe object to the supplied vector. Notice that this call requires a globe object and a vector to be intersected. The globe itself can be a projection (flat) or ellipsoidal . So does the ray-casting method rely on the curvature of the globe? The answer is "it depends" on which globe object is passed into the routine. In this example (I infer from the lat/lon coordinates subtended) that an ellipsoidal globe is being used, and "Yes" curvature is taken into account along with terrain elevation.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in a simple manner.  I understand the basics of what the code is doing, but not necessarily the math involved.  If you make that your answer, I'll give the bounty

Comment: Whoops, I mis-spoke; after reading through RayCastingSupport java code: the algorithm steps down the supplied vector towards the globe...at each step it tests (with an intersection function) to see if the test point is inside the terrain or not. If it is inside, the algorithm reverses direction and takes even smaller steps backing up to find the point where the vector meets the globe.   Does it account for ellipsoidal curvature? "It depends" on which globe is supplied becausethe "intersection" function tests  flatEarth globe and an Ellipsoidal globe returning slightly different results.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. This code does not take into account the earth curve. 
From what I could see, a ray trace is done for the center of the light but the cone of the light was drawn on an image (I am not sure about that, but it looks as if this example draws on an image of gray scale).
Any way this demo is about detecting hitting the ground to stop the ray trace. 
From what I understand, the algorithm stops after a distance set in the form (5km,10km ... 200km etc.)
I don't understand the direction of the ray. It makes sense to check for 200km radius only if you check light from out of space....
If you want to take the horizon into account you should check the pitch of the light source first. Its relevant for positive pitch values (above the horizon). 
In that case you should decide when to stop once the center of the light gets very high above ground. How high depends on whether you point your light towards a mountain slope of you terrain is relatively flat, or if the source of light is narrow beam or wide.